# Glyphicon-ok shows wrong symbol while using Bootstrap version v4.5.0 when deployed on the server

Tags: css

Glyphicon-ok shows the wrong symbol while using Bootstrap version v4.5.0 when deployed on the server. Please check the attached image. [Glyphicon image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L00vQ.png)
Does anyone how to fix this? Works fine in old version.

Comment: Glyphicon are dropped from Bootstrap v4 and later https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glyphicons are not supported in Bootstrap 4. You can try Font Awesome instead.

Comment: That's because they're fas, like this:
```
<i class="fas fa-check"></i>
<i class="fas fa-times"></i>
```
If you click on the font you want to use, you can see the page with its HTML snippet.

Comment: Did you remember to sign up a free account with fontawesome and link the free cdn in the <head> of html because these symbols work just fine for me.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks for your help.